# Remote branch not show in terminal?

Tags: git, gitlab, git-branch

My task is to commit somethings to other remote branch(not master) in gitlab. I have created another active remote branch name as Dennis (where the remote branch I want to commit to it) on the gitlab repository's branches part. However, it does not show the remotes/origin/Dennis branch  in the terminal. How I have remotes/origin/Dennis inside the git branch -a status? Otherwise, I can't commit file to remotes/origin/Dennis.

The git branch-a status is shown in my macbook terminal:

```
macbook$ git branch -a
* Dennis
  master
  remotes/origin/HEAD -> origin/master
  remotes/origin/master
```

Comment: It's not stated but I assume you have already fetched, haven't you?

Comment: haven't fetched. Sorry, I'm new to touch on the git

Comment: Well.... after you fetch, you will see the remote branch showing up. `git fetch --all`

Comment: I should explain, I guess... the thing is that you have a local repo... and there's another repo on gitlab. So... when things change on gitlab repo, you won't see those changes reflected (at least, in terms of seeing the remote branches change) unless you ask the local repo to get the information from the remote. This is what happens when you either run `git fetch` or when you run `git pull`.

Comment: @eftshift0 ic, thanks for the info. but actually why have to run git fetch --all command?

Comment: Because otherwise you won't get to see what happens on the remote... like, a new branch being created... or a branch getting new stuff committed.

Answer (score 2):

A simple [`git fetch`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-fetch) (no need for `--all`) should be enough.

Check the output of `git config --local -l` (done inside your repository).
If you see the [refspec](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Internals-The-Refspec):

```
remote.origin.fetch=+refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
```

That means a fetch will fetch *all* remote branches.

Answer (score 0):

`git fetch --prune`

In addition to @VonC's answer I also like to add --prune flag to the fetch command so that it can remove the remote branches that have been deleted from the list.